# Difference between the Amazon Linux 2 AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I launched both and they appear to be identical. One says `ebs` and the other is `gp2`.

```
ami-b270a8cf amzn2-ami-hvm-2017.12.0.20180328.1-x86_64-ebs
ami-f973ab84 amzn2-ami-hvm-2017.12.0.20180328.1-x86_64-gp2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference in that `ami-b270a8cf` `ebs` uses magnetic storage for the root volume and `ami-f973ab84` `gp2` uses General Purpose (SSD) storage for the root volume.

Comment: That's [not](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/375864b17daef1ac41a72d75c33fa191) really the case.

Answer (score 3):

AWS's lack of documentation explaining the actual difference between the two (if there is I'll gladly edit this answer) is a bit surprising so I'm adding my own take to this

#### TLDR;

If you're planning on switching to a faster SSD root volume at some point in the future but want to use Magnetic for now it would be better to use the `gp2` version of the AMI and then change the root volume to SSD sometime later

#### Some more Explanation

- `ami-f973ab84 amzn2-ami-hvm-2017.12.0.20180328.1-x86_64-gp2` - The *recommended* root volume type is General Purpose SSD (gp2)
- `ami-b270a8cf amzn2-ami-hvm-2017.12.0.20180328.1-x86_64-ebs` - The *recommended* root volume type is Magnetic

However this isn't set in stone so you can still interchange between them (I've used the `gp2` version with a Magnetic storage in the past without issues)

I couldn't find any official documentation as to the actual difference between the two AMI versions but the `gp2` version most likely has SSD related optimizations added already to the OS

So if you envision switching to SSD at some point in future but want to start with a Magnetic volume it might be better to just use the `gp2` optimized AMI right from the start. It probably has some optimizations not relevant to Magnetic volumes but it might be more future proof in case you want to have a faster root volume later